# Best way to structure SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have several database tables:

- `Client` (basic info, first name, last name, etc)
- `Employer` (basic info, employer name, fax, address, etc.)

I then have a junction table linking the two tables if required:

- `Client_Employer` (ClientID, EmployerID)

All of these tables are maintained with confirmed, accurate, clean data.

I have a fourth table that is used for informational purposes only and the data is neither clean, nor reliable as it is supplied by the end user and cannot be confirmed.

- `ClientEmployer` (data supplied by the client regarding their current employer)

I want to write a query that returns Client/Employer data if a record exists in the `Client_Employer` table, but will also fallback to the `ClientEmployer` table for employer information if none exists otherwise.

The columns in `Employer` match exactly the same columns in `ClientEmployer`.

I have looked at several options using `ISNULL()`, `CASE`, `IF/ELSE`, etc. but just want to see what others think the best, cleanest way to do this will be?

Comment: Think you've got your own table names mixed up in your description. Where does `Employer_Client` fit in?

Comment: can you specify the relationship between the tables? or how are the tables related with each other.

Comment: Typo... fixed. Should have been Client_Employer.

Comment: Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to drag in the partial data from `Client_Employer` and use `COALESCE()` for each column that you want to get from `Client_Employer` or one of the other tables.  Note that if there may be valid NULLs then you will need to use `CASE` based on another column, e.g. an Id, to determine which value to return.

Answer (score 1):

Well, making a few assumptions about the schema for ClientEmployer table, I'd combine a UNION and an EXISTS like this:

```
SELECT 
    cl.ClientID as ClientID, 
    em.EmployerID as employerID,
    cl.firstname, 
    cl.lastname, 
    em.employername, 
    em.fax, 
    em. address 
FROM 
    Client cl, 
    Employer em, 
    Client_Employer ce 
WHERE 
    cl.ClientID = ce.ClientID 
    and em.EmployerID = ce.EmployerID
UNION
SELECT 
    Clem.ClientID as clientID,
    -1 as EmployerID,
    clem.firstname, clem.lastname, 
    clem.employername, 
    clem.fax,
    clem.address 
FROM 
    ClientEmployer clem 

WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT * FROM Client cl, Employer em, Client_Employer ce 
                  WHERE cl.ClientID = ce.ClientID 
                        and em.EmployerID = ce.EmployerID 
                        and clem.ClientID = cl.ClientID
                        and clem.EmployerName = ce.EmployerName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ISNULL()` to `LEFT JOIN Employer`, like this:

```
SELECT 
  Client.*, 
  Employer.* 
FROM Client 
LEFT JOIN Client_Employer 
 ON Client_Employer.client_id = Client.id 
LEFT JOIN ClientEmployer 
 ON ClientEmployer.client_id = Client.id 
LEFT JOIN Employer 
 ON Employer.id = ISNULL(Client_Employer.employer_id, ClientEmployer.employer_id) 
WHERE Employer.id IS NOT NULL;
```

If some `Employer.id` is `NULL` (`WHERE` clause) so there aren't a relationship from a given `Client.id` in both Client/Employer tables, which means you'll have just the data which is in some of the Client/Employer tables.

Hope it works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

What about the usage of IF EXISTS?  Seems like you could pretty easily retrieve data where it exists, else select from ClientEmployer in your example where it does not exist.